# CakePHP HTMLHelper for Scripts uses extra param in URL causing scripts not to load

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-2.6

For our project we've been using a lot of subdomains, but for one particular section we just use a redirect that sends the user of a specific type from the normal dashboard at `/dashboard` to `/manager/dashboard`.

This has been in place for months and works, but now in an element within our view we're trying to load some scripts using the HTMLHelper, but it's appending the `/manager` to the URL.

How can I have it just access the webroot version at

```
/js/path
```

instead of

```
/manager/js/path
```

using a generic element that is used throughout our application in different subdomains like it doesn't now (with the exception of `/manager/*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
Configure::write('App.jsBaseUrl','js/');
```

to your `bootstrap.php` file.

Alternatively, if you provide the full path to the `.js` file (starting with a leading `/`), CakePHP will ignore whatever `App.jsBaseUrl` holds, and will render the correct path.